# Converting Json String to Json Object PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a json output as this

```
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "schedule": "{\"batch\": 1, \"times\": \"18:25:00.000000\"},{\"batch\": 1, \"times\": \"18:25:00.000000\"}"
    }
```

I want to display it like this

```
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "schedule": [{"batch": 1, "times": "18:25:00.000000"},
                     {"batch": 1, "times": "18:25:00.000000"}]
    }
```

I have tried everything I can think of, would appreciate some help

Comment: Please show how you generated the first output and it may be a simple fix to your code.

Comment: i got the data from MYSQL using  GROUP_CONCAT JSON_OBJECT then called it in PHP like this $schedule   = !empty($row['schedules']) ? $row['schedules'] : ''; and pass the var into an array like this $data[] = array (
     'id'   => $i,'schedule'   => $schedule,
    );

Comment: @user1550387 try using `$data[] = array ( 'id' => $i,'schedule' => json_decode($schedule, true))`;

Comment: "schedule": "\"{\\\"batch\\\": 1, \\\"times\\\": \\\"18:25:00.000000\\\"} which I had tried before and it not have I wanted

Comment: Paste a `var_dump($row['schedules']);`

Answer (score 0):

Neither your input JSON, nor your expected output JSON are well-formed. `json_decode()` returns `NULL` on both.

Without being exactly sure what your input looks like (or what your intended output would be), here is a demo of something that I suspect is what you're after. See comments for explanation.

```
<?php

// Your input JSON, corrected to well-formed syntax.
$string = '{"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "schedule": "{\"batch\": 1, \"times\": \"18:25:00.000000\"},{\"batch\": 1, \"times\": \"18:25:00.000000\"}"
    }]}';

// Convert into native array.
$array = json_decode($string, TRUE);
// Make 'schedule' an array of the two batches.
$array['data'][0]['schedule'] = json_decode("[{$array['data'][0]['schedule']}]", TRUE);

echo json_encode($array) . "\n";
// {"data":[{"id":1,"schedule":[{"batch":1,"times":"18:25:00.000000"},{"batch":1,"times":"18:25:00.000000"}]}]}
```

Comment: $sql = "call proc();";
  call_proc($url, $sql);
  $q      = $PDO->prepare($sql);
  $result = $q->execute();
  $numrowx = $q->rowCount();
  $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  
             while($row = $q->fetch()){ 
    $i = $i+1;
     $data[] = array (
     'id'   => $i,
     'schedule'   => !empty($row['schedule']) ? $row['schedule'] : '',
     ); 
   } 
   $response = array(
        'data'    => $data,
        );
        
            print_r(json_encode($response,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));

Comment: You contributions where helpful as it now have more like the data structure that that data is empty. I would update the full structure to give you more details

Comment: Yes, kindly share more data. Will gladly take a look.

Comment: {
 "returncode": null,
 "train": [
  {
   "id": 1,
   "schedule": "{\"batch\": 1, \"times\": \"04:21:00.000000\"},{\"batch\": 1, \"times\": \"04:21:00.000000\"},{\"batch\": 1, \"times\": \"04:21:00.000000\"}
  },}

Comment: This again is malformed. Please don't make any edits of your own on the data. If you need to censor, then change the values and their names, but please leave the format alone.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: No I did not get a real solution so, but user1550387 was close, just that no data was displayed but it got the structure right

Comment: You are user1550387 ;). The additional data you provided was malformed, making it impossible for me to further debug the issue without making very unwanted assumptions. If you're still stuck, send me some real and complete data and I'll take another look.